# How to fetch number of commits at Bitbucket using its API

Tags: json, rest, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

Is there a way to fetch the number of commits through the Bitbucket API and use it in a program?  I don't want to show any message or anything just the number of the commits by all the programmers in a section.

I've looked at the [API documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/changesets+Resource#changesetsResource-GETalistofcommentsonachangeset) but still wasn't able to do it.

Comment: I have read this https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/changesets+Resource#changesetsResource-GETalistofcommentsonachangeset but still dont know

Comment: I just update it, it works with API 2.0
Check my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66048328/5591888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following url to query the number of changesets:

```
https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/{account}/{repo}/changesets?limit=0
```

You have to change `{account}` and `{repo}` for the account an repository you want to know.  It will return a JSON with a `count` field denoting the number of commits in that repository.  Remember to set the `limit=0` parameter (which provides general info without listing the commits themselves).

### Example

To know the number of commits in the `atlassian-plugins` repo from `atlassian` using curl command line tool:

```
$ curl "https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/atlassian/atlassian-plugins/changesets?limit=0"
{"count": 4449, "start": null, "limit": 0, "changesets": []}
```

Check the first field, count, it shows that the repository has `1234` commits.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the answer, is there a way to find the count for all the repositories in one account? so you dont give a specific name to it?

Comment: Also how do I learn more about authentication ? for private repositoreis

Comment: I don't think there is a specific API call for the count of commits in all repositories in one account.  But you can try to get the [list of repositories](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/user+Endpoint#userEndpoint-GETalistofrepositoriesvisibletoanaccount) then loop through the list finding the count for each one.

Comment: About authentication, I find the section about [SSH protocol with Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket) quite interesting.  As a more simple (but potentially unsafe) solution you can add `https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/...` at the start of your API calls to authenticate.

Comment: Does SSH work for an Web App, I am showing the numbers on a graph for a website