# how to fetch the number of commits at Bitbucket using its API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

Is there a way to fetch the number of committed codes through the API for Bitbucket and use it in a program? I dont want to show any message or anything just the number of the committed code by all the programmers in a section

Answer (score 3):

I assume by 'comitted codes' you mean 'changesets'. 
From the [bitbucket REST api documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/changesets+Resource#changesetsResource-GETalistofchangesets):

> Gets a list of change sets associated with a
>   repository. By default, this call returns the 15 most recent
>   changesets. **It also returns the count which is the total number of
>   changesets on the repository**. Private repositories require the caller
>   to authenticate.

Use the following url (change 'username' and 'repository' to your own):

https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/username/repository/changesets?limit=0

For my test repo this returns:

> {"count": 2, "start": null, "limit": 0, "changesets": []}

Count is the total number of changesets. 'limit=0' means you will only get the 'count' back and no individual 'changeset' details.

**Edit:**

To get commits across all repositories would require some scripting. I used this java program to get all commits for a user across all repositories:

Requires these jars on the classpath

- [commons-logging-1.1.3.jar,](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi)
- [json-simple.1.1.1.jar,](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/list)
- [org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.3.4.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2)

-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;


public class BitBucket {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String username = "YOUR_USERNAME";
    String password = "YOUR_PASSWORD";
    String url = "https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/"+username;

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    Object obj = parser.parse(processRequest(url, username, password, client));

    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

    JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("values");
    Set<String> repoNames = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
        repoNames.add(((JSONObject) array.get(i)).get("name").toString());
    }

    long commitCount = 0;
    for(String repoName : repoNames){
        String repoUrl = "https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/"+username + "/" + repoName.toLowerCase() + "/changesets?limit=0";
        Object commitobj = parser.parse(processRequest(repoUrl, username, password, client));

        commitCount += (Long) ((JSONObject) commitobj).get("count");
    }
    System.out.println("Total Commit Count across "+repoNames.size() +" repos for user "+username+" = " + commitCount);

}

private static String getBasicAuthenticationEncoding(String username, String password) {

    String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(userPassword.getBytes()));
}

public static String processRequest(String url, String username, String password, HttpClient client) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

    request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + getBasicAuthenticationEncoding(username, password));

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + 
            response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }

    return result.toString();
}

}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, quick question so what happens if you want to see all the repositories for an accout. I dont want to {/repository/} fill this up for each project I want all of the repositories at the same time, can it be done?

Comment: See edited answer, includes additional information regarding script for all the repositories.

Answer (score -1):

I just extended this script from Atlassian forum for API v2.0 that works on 2021.
You can use it from: https://github.com/bc67da8d/bitbucket-commit-counter

Comment: I think this only works for bitbucket cloud services, that is using the rest API version 2. https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Does-the-rest-api-2-0-exist-for-server/qaq-p/881631